# Fixed password on source code. How secure it is?

Tags: php, security, authentication

I'm doing a very very simple web app for a friend of mine. He'll be the only one to access a restrict area, so my question is:

1. Is recommended to use a login with fixed password on source code like this: `if ($user_pass == 'myultrasecretpass')` ?
2. Is it secure? There's how to hack that?

I think it's no need to store user and password on database and some like that.

Please show me your ideas.

Comment: if ever your webserver config is broken and php files are served as direct source the password is exposed. therefore its usually better to store the password in an external file in a directory that is not served by your webserver and include that file in your php script.

Comment: IMHO I wouldn't do it. Use a DB with Salt and MD5

Comment: @PhillPafford then you have to store the DB password.

Comment: I suppose if the DB only allows local connections then my point is incorrect.

Comment: In addition to @Gryphius comment, it wouldn't hurt to just store the hash of the password instead of the password itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is no *less* secure to store the password in the source file provided it is not accessible to others. Otherwise you end up storing the db password, which would result in the same amount of security. The only way to hack it without any other access to the server is to use a brute force attack.

However, brute force attacks are a real world issue. To guard against them, you need to prevent a single IP from making too many requests too fast (e.g. limit to 5 tries in a minute before timing out and making the user wait for 10 minutes or something). Then the attacker would need a large number of computers with unique IP addresses to perform the attack.

Also, it goes without saying that the password needs to be sufficiently complex.

Make sure to have a username field as well, even if there is only one user. It greatly increases the complexity and makes brute force attacks much less likely.

Note that this assumes the database doesn't only allow local connections. If you do use a database that only allows local connections, then it is **definitely** more secure to use it to store sensitive information. In that case, even if the attacker gets the database password they won't be able to retrieve the information simply by logging in.

Comment: Yeah.. I thought these possibilities. I'll use a username field and any (don't know how yet) anti-brute force method. Anyway it's a simple project, no one will have interes to try any hack on this.

Answer (score 0):

Other considerations aside, what you've specified here can be easily bypassed, because of your choice of == .

That is, if I were to manage to get the value 0 into $user_pass, comparing $user_pass and *any* string value would evaluate to true.

Comment: Serious? I will try it, I'd never realized it.

Comment: Yeah. Easy to see how bugs can creep into code. I think "===" should take care of that concern.

Answer (score 0):

This is not secure for a couple of reasons.

There is no way to protect against a brute force attack.  (You aren't keeping track of bad login attempts).

If your web server fed the user the PHP page instead of executing it they would instantly have the password.

Comment: Brute force is a real threat and I thought about this too. I just doesn't undesrtand your secund reason.

Comment: Your web server decides to how to handle your diffirent files.  PHP files should be executed so the code is never seen by the user.  If for some reason it could be download like you can download an image or an html page they can view the source and see your password.

Comment: Oh yes, I know that but I'll host on a web hosting, I think no host will be incompetent like that, huh ?